# nginx web server index.php download

Tags: nginx, web-server

I am having trouble getting my index.php page to open. I am instead getting it as a randomly named download link. My configuration is pretty close to default.

server {

```
      listen 80;
      root /path/to/html/docs;
      index index.php;


      location / {
          autoindex on;
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
      }
```

}

I have tried switching off sendfile in nginx.conf andadding text/php to the gzip list of applications but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

nginx does not process php files so you have to pass it to an php-interpreter in order to generate the response. the recommended way is using php-fpm (PHP FastCGI Process Manager): https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/